# WP Mail SMTP by WPForms : Gmail Oauth connection disconnected only in one site

Tags: wordpress, smtp

I have several sites that are using WP Mail SMTP plugins with the same g-mail account. Today we noticed one site could not sent email and it had below error.

```
Email source: WPForms
Mailer: Google / Gmail
{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project." ,
"errors": [
{
"message": "Login Required.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"location": "Authorization",
"locationType": "header"
}
],
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
"domain": "googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"method": "caribou.api.proto.MailboxService.SendMessage",
"service": "gmail.googleapis.com"
}
}
]
}
}
For more details please try running an Email Test or reading the latest error event .
```

Then, I re-added the connection and it worked back. Does anyone know why this was happened. Thank you.